# Please check why this script not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Hi I want to create a simple url shortner script using the bitly api and jquery but the script is not working I am enable to find out why? Please correct the script mentioned below. Thanks.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputurl;
    var accessToken = "apikeyhere";

    $("#convertBtn").on('click',function(){
    inputurl = $("#inputurl").val();
    $("#longURL").html(inputurl);
    $("#shortURL").html("");

    var params = {
    "long_url" : inputurl
    };

    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + accessToken),
    };
    data: JSON.stringify(params)
    }).done(function(data){
    $("#shortURL").html(data.link);
    console.log(data.link);

    }).fail(function(data){
    $("#shortURL").html(data.link);
    console.log(data.link);
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="inputurl">
<button type="button" id="convertBtn">Convert</button>

<p> Long Url: <span id="longURL"></span></p>
<p> Short <span id="shortURL"></span></p>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: it's probably the error you're getting in the browser that stops it from working - i.e. the missing `});` at the end, the `;` that should be a `,` and the `,` that should be a `;` - and that's just the syntax errors that the browser developer tools will tell you about when loading the page - as for any other errors, you'll have to get the code running first, then go from there

Comment: *"Please check why this script not Working?"* cannot be a question title :( Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was you missed "})"
I marked it on the code with **

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputurl;
    var accessToken = "apikeyhere";

    $("#convertBtn").on('click',function(){
        inputurl = $("#inputurl").val();
        $("#longURL").html(inputurl);
        $("#shortURL").html("");

        var params = {
        "long_url" : inputurl
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            beforeSend: function (xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + accessToken)
            },
            success:function(data){
                $("#shortURL").html(data.link);
                console.log(data.link);
            },
            error:function(data){
                $("#shortURL").html(data.link);
                console.log(data.link);
            }
        });
    **});**
});
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Same as a question title cannot be *"Please check why this script not Working?"* - the first paragraph of an answer cannot simply state *"try this."*. Please - include more info on the changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var inputurl;
        var accessToken = "apikeyhere";
    
        $("#convertBtn").on('click',function(){
        inputurl = $("#inputurl").val();
        $("#longURL").html(inputurl);
        $("#shortURL").html("");
    
        var params = {
        "long_url" : inputurl
        };
    
        $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + accessToken)},
        data: JSON.stringify(params)
        }).done(function(data){
        $("#shortURL").html(data.link);
        console.log(data.link);
    
        }).fail(function(data){
        $("#shortURL").html(data.link);
        console.log(data.link);
        });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you noticed an alert stating that it's not desirable to post code answers only? Please describe in details the changes you made and the reasoning behind those.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @vishal-ve it showing net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID